# What is the nature of ocean waves in DEEP water?

Tags: waves, acoustics

My book says that it's both longitudinal and transverse, if yes then how?

Answer (score 3):

You have a misconception, probably. **Waves does not have to be just longitudinal or just transverse.** These are only models, usually used in basic explanation of 1D wave motion. You can have motions like this one which is clearly combination of both (see the rectangle sides both "inclining" and "breathing"):

[image]

Sure, the deeper, the "more longitudinal". Basically, the wave polarization is the trick (and the dispersion, for more complex wave structures). I will not provide the full derivation, cause there is a plenty of literature and online sources. For the basics and connections to other wave motions, I strongly recommend Ian G. Main's *Vibration and Waves in Physics*.

Comment: Question @VictorPira : How'd you make that animated gif at http://i.stack.imgur.com/aDfrs.gif Got a program for it, or what? Thanks.

Comment: It's just matlab plots merged to gif in gimp.